# winWait(autoit) alternative in watir 1.9 using rautomation

Tags: ruby, watir, rautomation

In our watir automation, there are several parts when we were wating pop ups with code like this:

```
win_exists = Watir.autoit.winWait('Message from webpage',5)
```

A few day ago, we were trying the new version of watir 1.9, that tries to replace the autoit with the rautomation :D(autoit works but in a dirty way).

What would be the equivalent in rautomation to this autoit method?

Protip: I suppose that someone who can create the tag rautomation will have a new badge (not enough points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent for that code would be:

```
win_exists = RAutomation::Window.new(:title => "Message from webpage").exists? # true/false
```

You can read more about RAutomation from it's web page at https://github.com/jarmo/RAutomation/blob/master/README.rdoc or from one of the blog posts i've written in the past at http://www.itreallymatters.net/post/2352350743/automating-windows-and-their-controls-with-ruby